# How to detect properly Windows, Linux & Mac operating systems

Tags: c#, macos, mono, cross-platform

I could not found anything really efficient to detect correctly what platform (Windows / Linux / Mac) my C# progrma was running on, especially on Mac which returns Unix and can't hardly be differenciated with Linux platforms !

So I made something less theoretical, and more practical, based on specificities of Mac.

I'm posting the working code as an answer. Please, comment if it works well for you too / can be improved.

Thanks !

**Response :**

Here is the working code !

```
    public enum Platform
    {
        Windows,
        Linux,
        Mac
    }

    public static Platform RunningPlatform()
    {
        switch (Environment.OSVersion.Platform)
        {
            case PlatformID.Unix:
                // Well, there are chances MacOSX is reported as Unix instead of MacOSX.
                // Instead of platform check, we'll do a feature checks (Mac specific root folders)
                if (Directory.Exists("/Applications")
                    & Directory.Exists("/System")
                    & Directory.Exists("/Users")
                    & Directory.Exists("/Volumes"))
                    return Platform.Mac;
                else
                    return Platform.Linux;

            case PlatformID.MacOSX:
                return Platform.Mac;

            default:
                return Platform.Windows;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well I'll post the answer in 8 hours when I'll be allowed to do so :)

Comment: If you have working code, edit your question and include it in the question.

Comment: Yes it is what I was doing :) Why -1 ?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this to be a complete case, for example, what if my linux had been configured with all of those directories...wouldn't be impossible...

Comment: Indeed if thos directories were existing on a Linux install, it would be reported as Mac, but I had to find a workaround to the mono problem that quite never reports PlatformID.MacOSX but PlatformID.Unix indifferently on Linux and Mac. Do you think of a way to better recognize it ?

Comment: I hate to necro a long-dead question, but there is a rather simple solution to this issue. Any Unix based os by default contains the `uname` command. If the result of the code above returns `Platform.Unix`, one could start a subprocess running `uname -o`, filter the results on wether they contain `linux` or `darwin`, and then return the corresponding enum value accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe check out the [IsRunningOnMac](https://github.com/jpobst/Pinta/blob/1.6/Pinta.Core/Managers/SystemManager.cs#L125) method in the Pinta source:

Comment: Thanks, it seems to use p/invoke. Will it work every time or are there chances mono complains about that ?

Answer (score 9):

Per the remarks on the [Environment.OSVersion Property page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The Environment.OSVersion property does not provide a reliable way to
>   identify the exact operating system and its version. Therefore, we do
>   not recommend that you use this method. Instead: To identify the
>   operating system platform, use the RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform
>   method.

[RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.isosplatform?view=netframework-4.7.2) worked for what I needed.

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
{
    // Your OSX code here.
}
elseif (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
{
    // Your Linux code here.
}
```